# While loop not looping more than once in java

Tags: java, loops, tcp, while-loop, switch-statement

This won't loop more than once, so I am unable to check if I have a client message:

```
 new Thread() {    
   public void run() {
     while(true) {
       for(int I=0; I<numPlayers; I++) {
         if(!players[I].isConnected()) {
           players[I].drop();
           System.out.println("Client disconnected!");
           players[I]=null;
           readers[I]=null;
           writers[I]=null;
           numPlayers--;
         }
         try {
           System.out.println(readers[I].ready());
           if(readers[I].ready()) {
             BufferedReader reader = readers[I];
             System.out.println("Reading");
             switch(reader.read()) {
              case PacketID.Connect:
                System.out.println("Connect");
                players[I].name=reader.readLine();
                PrintWriter writer=writers[I];
                writer.write(PacketID.Connect);
                writer.write(MaxPlayers);
                writer.write(numPlayers);
                for(int I2=0;I2<numPlayers;I2++){
                  writer.println(players[I2].name);
                  players[I2].sendMessage(
                    "Client "+players[I].name+" has connected!");
                }
                writer.flush();
                break;
              case PacketID.Ready:
                System.out.println("lolol lol");
                break;
            }
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
   }
 }.start();
```

I can see people saying my code is messy and inefficient.
I'm going to clean it all up later
Also I don't know why stack overflow is malformatting my code.

Comment: You're modifying one of the loop's conditionals (numplayers) within the loop. that's almost never a good idea.

Comment: The player isn't disconnecting, nor does it say it is. So I doubt that is the reason. And I'm talking about the while loop in general, it's not repeating itself.

Comment: You say you'll clean it up later - but this is a textbook example of why it's better to write clean code rather than clean it up later! If you'd formatted it properly and used a for loop rather than a while loop without any break statements then the solution would probably be a heck of a lot easier to find, perhaps even obvious.

Comment: It's not really needing cleaning up, more of making more efficient.

Comment: Are you not getting any errors at all?  I'd do something like this.  1)  Make sure you put some sleeps in there.  If no players than you will be in a really really really tight loop.  2)  put a try catch around the entire contents of the while loop.  Catch both exception and runtime exception.  You might be thorwing a null pointer somewhere that isn't be proped up because it is in it's own thread

Comment: None. I just wrapped the loop in a try, didn't error out there either.

Comment: Can you post your console output?

Comment: Sure: (800 or so Hi's)
Hi
Hi
false
Hi

Comment: That is not in the code you posted. :)

Comment: So you never see any of the output from inside the while loop?

Comment: I updated it to output Hi in the beginning of the while loop.

Comment: Have you tried running the code without the added baggage of the thread? Also please name the variables in lowercase (i'm picky about such things sorry)

Comment: can you describe when isConnected is set to true?  is it before everything else is initialized, or after???

Comment: I come from a background of various languages which made it a habit. I can try to make it nonthreaded

Comment: isConnected simply detects if the client is connected. When isConnected is false, the client has no active connection the the server.

Comment: I get that.  When a client connects, what is set first.... the boolean flag? or do you initialize the readers/writers and then set the flag?  If you set the flag first, your reader could be null.  The line System.out.println(readers[i].ready()) could be throwing nulls.

Comment: It's detected on the time it's call. I don't get any null errors and everything is try'd. But yeah, it requires the reader to be prepared in order for it to be detected which it is

Comment: `It's not really needing cleaning up, more of making more efficient.` No need for cleanup? So why you don't see the reason? I **always** do all possible cleanup before debugging hard or asking.

Comment: Can you not step through the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, using isConnected hung the server

Answer (score 2):

Your logic of looping on

```
for(int I=0;I<numPlayers;I++)
```

is flawed because it assumes no "holes" in the players array. What if you have 3 players connected (0,1,2) and player #0 disconnects? You'll decrement "numPlayers" and never look at player #2 again.

Also, you don't appear to be checking for null in your `readers` and `writers` array, so you no sooner set `readers[I]=null` then you start trying to reference it.

```
   ...
    readers[I]=null;
    writers[I]=null;
    numPlayers--;
   }
    try {
    System.out.println(readers[I].ready());
     ...
```

Odds are you're throwing a null pointer exception somewhere in all this, and not seeing it because you're running the whole thing in a thread.

Answer (score 1):

`reader.read()` might be blocking for input

Comment: I never get a message that tells me it's reading, so it can't be that. Also, the client does it fine

Comment: Can you confirm that the loop finishes the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Some misplaced break statement might be breaking out of the while loop.

Comment: I thought about that, but couldn't find any yet. I'll look again.

Comment: I don't know why it's pasting like that in stackoverflow, i'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does look correct as far the while loop goes. Are there any exceptions being thrown. That will be only reason.

Comment: IDEA confirms that the only way out of the loop is with an exception.

Comment: I may have found the source. It stops the loop whenever a client connects-- probably from the switch statement?

Comment: If it's a blocking read, it hasn't really stopped looping.  It's just waiting.

Comment: Or maybe it does not exit the while loop, but just does nothing in there (i.e. does not enter the for loop). Are you sure it exits the loop? Can you print something on every iteration and on exit?

Comment: I have, i printed Hi every iteration at the beginning of the while loop. When I connect a client, it haults with no message after.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the try in an else statement?
You probably don't want to read anything from the reader that is `null`!

Comment: I have a try encased in the whole thing

Comment: Okay think about it like this.  The loop runs fine, a player connects, and then the loop stops.  Could it be cause isConnected is being set before reader/writer/player is being set?  You are in a pretty tight loop....

Answer (score 0):

I have not run your example but my thought process is as follows - the thread starts and runs to completion. That is why I asked if you can try to run the code without the thread. That may help you isolate your issue. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Based on the print out (Hi false ..), I think readers[i].ready() is actually returning false and that is what stopping you from reading. I am not sure who sets the "ready" to be true. No exception, just simple dropping off the loop.. :)